# while loop and sets in python

Tags: python, loops, set

I am writing a function that takes `int` input from user from a predefined list and adds it to a set. The code is working perfectly fine until it gets where all (11) items have been added to the set. It just keeps going and going. Is it because of the set or a logical error with my code?

```
def append_guess(n):

    list_of_numbers = [1, 11, 7, 8, 12, 6, 15, 30, 5, 3, 2]
    guessed = set()

    while (n):
        try:
            n = int(input("Enter an integer between 1-30 >> "))
            if n in list_of_numbers:
                print("right guess")
                guessed.add(n)
                print(guessed)
            else:
                print("Wrong Guess - Keep Trying!! ")
        except:
            if guessed == set(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 30):
                print("Great Job! You have Guessed All numbers")
                break

append_guess(1)
```

Comment: There is nothing that would cause an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You used  `try` and `except` incorrectly. They should not be used for regular program logic in general. They are only to be used for handling exceptions. Also you do not need both a list and a set containing the same numbers for the correct guesses.

Instead, put the check as the condition of the while loop. So maybe something like this:

```
correct_set = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 30}
guessed = set()

while guessed != correct_set:
    n = int(input("Enter an integer between 1-30 >> "))
    if n in correct_set:
        print("right guess")
        guessed.add(n)
        print(guessed)
    else:
        print("Wrong Guess - Keep Trying!! ")

print("Great Job! You have Guessed All numbers")
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of the function is, but if you were to break it into functions, you can separate the input and checking logic like the following. Also I would consider using a better name for "n", call it "guess" perhaps? So something like this:

```
def append_guess(guess, correct_set, guessed):
    if guess in correct_set:
        print("right guess")
        guessed.add(guess)
        print(guessed)
    else:
        print("Wrong Guess - Keep Trying!! ")
    return guessed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    correct_set = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 30}
    guessed = set()

    while guessed != correct_set:
        guess = int(input("Enter an integer between 1-30 >> "))
        guessed = append_guess(guess, correct_set, guessed)

    print("Great Job! You have Guessed All numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the while loop condition to `len(guessed) < len(list_of_numbers)` so that when all the numbers from the `list_of_numbers` have been guessed and added to the set, the while loop terminates

Code block

```
def guessing_game():
    list_of_numbers = [1, 11, 7, 8, 12, 6, 15, 30, 5, 3, 2]
    guessed = set()

    while len(guessed) < len(list_of_numbers):
        n = int(input("Enter an integer between 1-30 >> "))
        if n in list_of_numbers:
            print(f"You guessed {n} which is correct")
            guessed.add(n)
        else:
            print("Wrong guess keep trying")
    print("You completed the game")
guessing_game()
```

With this code block you don't need the try except as the code will correctly exit once all numbers have been guessed

Comment: i tried, did not work. i am still beginner to python and programming in general. would it be possible to share functional block of code with what you have advised previously?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a functional block

Comment: thank you for the great contribution and inspiration!

Answer (score -1):

This has worked perfectly fine

def append_guess():

```
list_of_numbers = [1, 11, 7, 8, 12, 6, 15, 30, 5, 3, 2]
guessed = set()

while len(guessed) != len(list_of_numbers):
    n = int(input("Enter an integer between 1-30 >> "))
    if n in list_of_numbers:
        print("right guess")
        guessed.add(n)
        print(guessed)

    elif n not in list_of_numbers:
        print("Wrong Guess - Keep Trying!! ")

print("Great Job! You have Guessed All numbers!")
```

append_guess()